# How do you fix this PracticeIt Classes Inheritence rounding bug?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

[Practice It link (because I cannot post pictures and this is where I found the practice problem)](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/practiceit/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+9&problem=bjp3-9-e10-DiscountBill)

How do you fix this PracticeIt Classes Inheritence rounding bug? Apparently it only malfunctions in the getDiscountPercent() method.

```
public class DiscountBill extends GroceryBill{
    boolean p;
    double totalD;
    double total2;
    double total;
    int count;
    
    
    public DiscountBill(Employee clerk, boolean preferred){
        super(clerk);
        p = preferred;
    }
    
    public void add(Item i){
        super.add(i);
            total2 += i.getPrice();
        if(p){
            totalD+=i.getDiscount();
            total += (i.getPrice() - i.getDiscount());
            if(i.getDiscount() > 0.000){
                count++;
            }
            
        }else{
            total+= i.getPrice();
        }
    }
    public int getDiscountCount(){
       return count;
    }
    public double getDiscountAmount(){
        return totalD;
    }
    public double getDiscountPercent(){
         return 100.0 * (total2-total) /total2;
    }
    public double getTotal(){
        return (double)Math.round(total * 100d) / 100d;
    }
}
```

Instead of returning 16.6421928536466, it returns 16.64219285364659.

[Practice It link (you can copy and paste this code and try to solve it here)](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/practiceit/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+9&problem=bjp3-9-e10-DiscountBill)

Comment: The error is `0.00000000000001`, which is well within reason for floating-point error. If you use `double` or `float` values, you encounter this sort of imprecision (which is an argument for not using `==` with double values). If it's not acceptable for you, then use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Some decimal values (for example 1.3) can only be represented exactly in binary with an infinitely repeating pattern of bits.  This is just like how an integer divided by another integer produces a rational quotient with an infinitely repeating pattern of digits after the decimal point.  Clearly, there aren't infinite bits in a `double`, so it is rounded to the closest possible representation.